# /g conversion from javascript regext to groovy regex

Tags: javascript, regex, groovy

I have a regex in javascript `/[^A-Za-z0-9\+\/\=]/g` which is for

```
remove all characters that are not A-Z, a-z, 0-9, +, /, or =
```

So in groovy the above regex would be : `/[^A-Za-z0-9\+\/\=]*$`

is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

No.

You use the `replaceAll()` method:

```
myStr = (myStr =~ /[^A-Za-z0-9\+\/\=]/).replaceAll("")
```

Comment: Or: `myStr = myStr.replaceAll( ~/[^A-Za-z0-9+\/=]/, "" )`

Comment: Or: `myStr = myStr.replaceAll(~/[^\w\d\+\/\=]/, "")`